# How can I update a google chrome browser extension to use Google's new code signature?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, digital-signature, code-signing

**How can an end-user manually/locally update the code signature for an extension?**

I used to use a [google chrome extension](https://support.1password.com/kb/202203/), which broke 1 year ago because of Google Chrome's updated code signature. How can I manually update the extension (it's not going to be updated by the developer) - it's still compatible apart from the code signature.

If this is the wrong site: Sorry - please let me know where I should have posted. Thanks!

Not sure where to start or what tools to use. There are [articles on self-signing certificates](https://dgu2000.medium.com/working-with-self-signed-certificates-in-chrome-walkthrough-edition-a238486e6858) but not sure those would apply.

Comment: AFAIK, you can only unpack the extension and load it in developer mode on chrome://extensions page.